# attrchange.js not forcing style change (jQuery + CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have linked in attrchange.js to the document, and used this code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').attrchange({
     callback: function ($event) {
       if ($event.attributeName === 'style') {
         $('.article-title').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
         console.log($(this));
       }
     }
   });
  });
```

The item where the style is set is a `<body>` tag, the colour of which is dynamically set by a template:

```
<body class="body" style="background-color: #6e7783;">
```

The item which needs to be modified is here:

```
<h1 class="article-title article-title-color-swap">Football</h1>
```

I want `attrchange.js` to observe the style attached to the body tag, and then to apply the background-color to the `.article-title` post. Why is attrchange.js not forcing the style change?

This is an extension from another question. Currently my issue is with attrchange.js, and therefore I deemed this to be a separate question to the previous.

Comment: does it get inside the if statement?

Comment: How would I test this?

Comment: Just put a console.log("INSIDE"); inside of the if statement and check the conosle log within the page inspector .

Comment: I have editted the code above to include a console.log(this); within the if statement - it doesn't seem to the register anything.

Comment: try $(this) inside the log instead of just this

Comment: `console.log($(this));`

That's been added - but no response. I think it's not getting inside the if statement. How would you achieve this?

Comment: is the style set before your code runs?

Comment: That I don't know - it's based on a template, therefore I am not technically setting the style. How would I ensure that the order is correct? This code is added in the footer?